# How do I track app service name on Application Insights during PageView?

Tags: azure-application-insights

Using Angular SPA and Application Insights. How do I track which App Service served the request in the logs?

```
"@microsoft/applicationinsights-angularplugin-js": "^3.0.0",
"@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.8.9",
```

Comment: Could you please share your code, where your have configured ApplicationInsights.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps to create Application Insights for `Angular SPA` and track the events and `PageViews`.

In `Azure Portal`, Create Application Insights.

[image]

Followed [angular-cli - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli) to create Angular Application.

```cs
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-appangular
cd my-appangular
ng serve
```

Thanks @[Ranjit Saini](https://software-ranjit.medium.com/how-to-integrate-azure-application-insights-to-an-angular-application-15ffff977cc6) for the clear steps to Integrate AppInsights in Angular Application.

- Open the Application in `VSCode`.Navigate to the Application Root Directory and run the below command to Install the `applicationinsights` dependencies.

```
npm install applicationinsights-js --save
```

- In `package.json`,under `dependencies`,  add the `ApplicationInsights` Package.

```cs
"@microsoft/applicationinsights-web":"~2.4.4"
```

[image]

- Create a new folder with name environment and add a new file with name `environment.ts`.
- Add the below code in it.

```cs
export  const  environment = {
    production:false,
    appInsights: {
        instrumentationKey:  '********'
    }
};
```

- Copy the Instrumentation Key from `ApplicationInsights` and paste it in `environment.ts`.

[image]

- Create a new folder with name `service`.
- Add a new file in `service` folder with name `logging.service.ts`.
- In the newly created  `logging.service.ts` file, Add the below code related to tracking the `pageViews`, `logs` and `events`.

***My  `logging.service.ts` file :***

```cs
import { ApplicationInsights } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';  
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppMonitoringService {
    appInsights: ApplicationInsights;
    constructor() {
        this.appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
            config: {
                instrumentationKey: '5a81860a-6144-40fc-80ff-25bd3371d3d1',  
                enableAutoRouteTracking: true
            }
        });
        this.appInsights.loadAppInsights();
    }
    setUserId(userId: string) {
        this.appInsights.setAuthenticatedUserContext(userId);
    }
    clearUserId() {
        this.appInsights.clearAuthenticatedUserContext();
    }
    logPageView(name?: string, uri?: string) {
        this.appInsights.trackPageView({
            name: name,
            uri: uri
        });
    }
      logPageView1(name: string, average: number, properties?: { [key: string]: any }) {
         this.appInsights.trackPageView({
             name: "My Page View",
             properties: {
             ServiceName:  "My Service" }});        
    }
    logEvent(name: string, properties?: { [key: string]: any }) {
        this.appInsights.trackEvent({ name: name }, properties);
        
    }
    logMetric(name: string, average: number, properties?: { [key: string]: any }) {
        this.appInsights.trackMetric({ name: name, average: average }, properties);
        
    }
    logException(exception: Error, severityLevel?: number) {
        this.appInsights.trackException({ exception: exception, severityLevel: severityLevel });
    }
   
    logTrace(message: string, properties?: { [key: string]: any }) {
        this.appInsights.trackTrace({ message: message }, properties);
    }
}
```

- Integrate `AppMonitoringService` from `logging.service.ts` in `app.component.ts`.
- In ``, First add the `AppMonitoringService` in providers.

```cs
providerapp.module.tss: [ AppMonitoringService]
```

***My `app.module.ts` file:***

```cs
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppMonitoringService } from 'src/service/logging.service';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [AppMonitoringService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

- Inject the `AppMonitoringService` in `app.component.ts`.

***My `app.component.ts` file:***

```cs
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApplicationInsights, IExceptionTelemetry, DistributedTracingModes } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AppMonitoringService } from 'src/service/logging.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-appangular';
  constructor(private azAppInsightService: AppMonitoringService) {
  }
}
```

Now run the application using `ng serve`.

[image]

[image]

- Check the `Application Insights` for traces.

[image]

[image]

- Deploy the App to Azure App Service and now check the traces.