# How to configure azure appinsights in angular 16?

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, single-page-application, appinsights

I have followed below article to implement appinsights in angular 16 app.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-add-application-insights-to-an-angular-spa/

In appInsights service class, I have below code.

```
import { ApplicationInsights } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';
import { environment } from 'src/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppinsightsService {

  instance: ApplicationInsights;

  constructor() {
     
    this.instance = new ApplicationInsights({ config: {
      instrumentationKey: environment.appInsights.instrumentationKey,
    //  enableCorsCorrelation: true,
      enableAutoRouteTracking: true
    } });
     
    this.instance.loadAppInsights();
    this.instance.trackPageView();
     
  }
```

environment.ts file has below code

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    baseApiUrl: 'http://localhost:5257/api',
    appInsights: {
      instrumentationKey: 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxx-xx'
    }
  };
```

Added appinsights service dependency in the constructor of app component as below

```
constructor(private appInsightsService: AppinsightsService) {

}
```

Not sure what was missing,but somehow appinsights is not logging anything.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Make sure you Instrumentation key is Corerct in `environment.ts`.

Comment: Could you please share the Screenshot of the transaction Search in Application Insights.

Comment: Thanks Harshitha. I'm able to view PAGE VIEW, DEPENDENCY logs in Transaction Search in AppInsights. But I'm not getting why Server response time, Server requests are empty in Overview. Any idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

Iam able to log traces and requests to Application Insights from `Angular 16 App`.

***My Angular Version:***

[image]

Along with the document which you have given I have also followed the blog by [Ranjit Saini](https://software-ranjit.medium.com/how-to-integrate-azure-application-insights-to-an-angular-application-15ffff977cc6).

Thanks @Ranjit Saini for the steps.

***App Insights Traces:***

[image]

***Performance:***

[image]

> Not sure what was missing,but somehow appinsights is not logging anything.

- Instead of getting the Instrumentation Key from `environment.ts` file, once try to set the Instrumentation Key in the `logging.service.ts`  file.
- If you still face issue, deploy the application to Azure, Enable the Application Insights and check the logs.

Refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75247644/how-do-i-track-app-service-name-on-application-insights-during-pageview/75283550#75283550) for more details.